# How to implement Libreoffice icon style via the terminal command line?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, libreoffice

Is it possible to implement [Libreoffice icon style](https://libreofficehelp.com/change-libreoffice-default-look-and-feel/) via the terminal command line? If yes, how do i do this?

To clarify, I would like to achieve in cmdline that which is described in the section "How to apply Icon Styles in LibreOffice" in the hyperlink.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Can you elucidate please?

Comment: @Graham please see edited question.

Comment: What version of LibreOffice are you using? The latest version is 6.3 https://libreofficehelp.com/libreoffice-6-3-fresh-released-download-install/ If you change parameters in LO it is usual for those changes to persist after closing so I am confused as to why you need to attempt to make changes from the command line. You have not really explained this sufficiently to encourage responses.

Comment: Find icon style setup in the file `~/.config/libreoffice/>x</user/registrymodifications.xcu` (search for `SymbolStyle` value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon styles are in `/usr/share/libreoffice/share/config`

```
$ ls -1
images_breeze_dark.zip
images_breeze_svg.zip
images_breeze.zip
images_colibre.zip
images_helpimg.zip
images_tango.zip
$
```

LibreOffice stores most user-set values in *~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu*.

The icon names used in *~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu* exclude *images_* and *.zip* and aren't exactly the same as those seen in the *Tools > Options > View > Icon style* dropdown.

[image]

Currently, I'm using *breeze_dark*:

```
$ grep -i breeze registrymodifications.xcu 
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Common/Misc"><prop oor:name="SymbolStyle" oor:op="fuse"><value>breeze_dark</value></prop></item>
$
```

So if I want use *colibre* instead, , I would run

```
sed -ie 's/breeze_dark/colibre'
```

**Caution**: you need to run the `sed` command only after ensuring that no LibreOffice process is running.

---

The process is the same in LibreOffice 6.3.1 as it is in LibreOffice 6.0.7.

Comment: Excellent! It's all in that "SymbolStyle" line that you had mentioned. :)